# AutoComplete textbox in ASP.NET with VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

In my ASP.NET Project I have one dropdown list. I'm bounding values using dataset. Instead of using dropdown list I want to use textbox with autocomplete mode. While user entering text the suggestions should be displayed. How can I acheive this task with the same dataset. I have googled this question and I didn't find anything relevant to my problem. Please guide me to acheive this task in simple way. Thanks in Advance.

The dropdown list databind coding is as follows :

```
If HasDataSetRows(dsResult, 0) Then
      ddlTowardsAcc.DataSource = dsResult.Tables(0)
      ddlTowardsAcc.DataValueField = "ACC_ID"
      ddlTowardsAcc.DataTextField = "ACC_NAME"
      ddlTowardsAcc.DataBind()
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Its binding correctly. To user `AutoComplete` you need to add [JqueryUi](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/). Add `CSS` and relevant `Scripts` for it and just call below code on your page.

```
// onLoad
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select').combobox();
});
```

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nickaknudson/fsRn4/4/)